# Start program when a device connects to local wifi

Tags: pi-3, python

I'm looking for a python program that could detect when device has connected to a local wifi and start a specific program. And would communicate via SMS with raspberry pi.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing program or do you want someone to write it for you? And how would it communicate via SMS with raspberry pi?

Comment: A1. I was hoping there was an existing one. Or at least pointed in the right direction. A2. I'm still looking into how it could communicate via sms. Just simple questions that could be answered via sms and placed in certain queues.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to be answered in full.

A)

Why do you need python to check if a device connected? Shellscript would be much faster and waste less memory. Also, **wich network** are you monitoring?

Does the pi hang in an existing wlan, or does it provide a local hotspot?

If you want to check into an existing network, you could modify a python portscanner to look for devices instead of ports, but I won't code it for you, sry mate. Or did I get you wrong, and the python script shall be running on a laptop, because

B)

Why would you send a sms to your raspberry? This assumes that the python script would not run on the raspberry itself. If you want to know how to send sms, [GSM module is what you need](https://www.amazon.de/Starall-1800-1900-Entwicklungsboard-Modul-Arduino/dp/B079M6L8G9/ref=pd_day0_hl_147_6/261-3297493-4031617?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B079M6L8G9&pd_rd_r=9c258fb8-9e6a-11e9-8b68-9760d91a4974&pd_rd_w=g2yKy&pd_rd_wg=fJ1Xi&pf_rd_p=2201c3c9-4bbe-45b3-9e49-7948d9b16246&pf_rd_r=VK2W2WB0BW74EJDNV8X7&psc=1&refRID=VK2W2WB0BW74EJDNV8X7)

To me, this question looks really fishy. I am not helping you to build a assasination bomb device. At least not until you'd pay me 10 k ^^

Comment: There are most questions but no real answer to the problem.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288176/is-showing-effort-needed

Comment: I do not understand what that discussion shall tell me. I'm looking at our policies https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The question is of type "I want that, pls give it to me or code it for me". OP did not at least try googeling, nor did he try to code something together himself so we could help him debug. Why should we take effort in answering, if OP does not show any effort himself, say, at least try and google something up....